# Mule flow terminate

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I have a small question. Do we have any option to stop/terminate the flow where ever we want in Mulesoft 4? Example: After executing transform message or after logger processor want to stop/terminate the flow based on our business requirement.

Comment: Why do you need to stop it? When it would need to be activated again?

Comment: I want to terminate the execution after executing one processor example: one of the transform messages.     Example - I have http listener, set payload, transform message and logger. I want to stop after executing transform message and it would not need to be activate any more.

Answer (score 1):

Two different ways to achieve that are described in the KB article https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Stop-Or-Start-Flows-In-Mule-4-x-Programmatically

Basically you need to get an instance of the Mule registry, the lookup the flow and stop or start it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make use of groovy script or java class to start/stop mulesoft at runtime. Drag and drop the scripting component from the palette and choose groovy as your engine and use the script below.

```
flowName = registry.lookupByName('flowName').get();
      if (flowName.isStarted())
        flowName.stop()
      else 
        flowName.start()
```